# Watir - Find elements using partial text

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

Is there a way to find an element by the text it contains?

Given:

`<div>foobar</div>`

```
browser.div(text: contains('foo')).present?   
# => true
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! Just use a regular expression:

`browser.div(text: /foo/).present?`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!